# Textfield material design objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, material-design

How can I show a textfield with material design?

I need this like floating labels without CocoaPods.

[image]

Comment: You would need to create a series of actions and animations that respond to various touch and resignFirstResponder events.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use two images for custom UITextfield First image for editing UITextfield and second image for not editing image which will be your default custom UITextfield image.

you can achieve this by simply setting first image as a Background image of  UITextfield while editing `textFieldDidBeginEditing`

set second background image of UITextfield on `textFieldShouldEndEditing`

Answer (score 1):

You can just download & import two files of SkyFloatingLabelTextField.swift and UITextField+fixCaretPosition.swift

Thereafter, associate SkyFloatingLabelTextField class to the textfield where you want such floating.

Download File from this url link:
https://github.com/Skyscanner/SkyFloatingLabelTextField